# TeXstudio - Make recognition of bibliography changes work with output_directory parameter

Tags: biblatex, miktex, biber, texstudio

I have a problem regarding TeXstudio (on a Windows machine, using MiKTeX) and the `output_directory` parameter of `biber`. I changed this parameter together with the `pdflatex` parameter `aux-directory`, so that the entries in the configuration menu looked like this:

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -aux-directory=temp %.tex
biber.exe  --output_directory=temp %
```

This worked great so far. All the aux and `biber` processing files were stored in the subfolder "temp". Today though, I noticed that some TeXstudio specific functionalities are missing:

If I include a new entry in my bib-file, the program does not recognize the change. That means, no new entries are suggested through the auto-complete feature. Additionally, the compiling process after pressing the <kbd>F1</kbd> key does not include `biber` compilation.

If I set the preferences back to normal, everything works fine again. Does anyone know how it is able to use these features, but with the possibility of a tidy folder structure?